# How to use different types for kotlin delegation properties

Tags: android, kotlin, properties, android-livedata, delegation

I try to write a LiveData class which wraps the original ( nullable ) value into a **Result** class, clearly indicating whether there is a value ( **Result.Success** ) or not ( **Result.Failure** ).
Throughout the entire application I used this class to distinguish whether the process of loading some files was successful or not. So for that reason I decided to use it in my LiveData subclass as well, even though the naming is not as reasonable as it could be. To make life easier there're some fluent helper methods to execute code in the different cases.

```
sealed class Result<out T: Any> {
    data class Success<out T: Any>(val value: T): Result<T>()
    object Failure: Result<Nothing>()

    fun onSuccess(block: (T) -> Unit): Result<T> {
        if(this is Success) {
            block(value)
        }

        return this
    }

    fun onFailure(block: () -> Unit): Result<T> {
        if(this is Failure) {
            block()
        }

        return this
    }

    fun handle(onSuccess: (T) -> Unit, onFailure: () -> Unit): Result<T> {
        if(this is Success) {
            onSuccess(value)
        } else {
            onFailure()
        }

        return this
    }
}
```

So I need the ability to *set* a value of type T but *get* a wrapping Result - object.
The easy way is to use functions like *setValue(value: T)* to change the value and *getValue(): Result* to receive the value safely. But I would like to use kotlin's delegated properties ( **SafeMutableLiveDataDelegation** ) to do so.

```
abstract class SafeLiveData<T: Any> {
    abstract val value: Result<T>
}

class SafeMutableLiveData<T: Any>: SafeLiveData<T>() {
    private val mutableValue = MutableLiveData<T>()
    override var value by SafeMutableLiveDataDelegation(mutableValue)

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): SafeMutableLiveData<T> {
        return this
    }

    fun ifAvailable(block: (T) -> Unit): SafeMutableLiveData<T> {
        value.onSuccess(block)

        return this
    }

    fun ifNotAvailable(block: () -> Unit): SafeMutableLiveData<T> {
        value.onFailure(block)

        return this
    }

    fun handle(ifAvailable: (T) -> Unit, ifNotAvailable: () -> Unit): SafeMutableLiveData<T> {
        value.handle(ifAvailable, ifNotAvailable)

        return this
    }
}
```

Using only readonly access ( override val value by... ) everything's fine but how to create a delegation class which can do so? Something like that:

```
private class SafeMutableLiveDataDelegation<T: Any>(private val mutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<T>) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): Result<T> {
        return  if(mutableLiveData.value != null)
            Result.Success(mutableLiveData.value!!)
        else
            Result.Failure
    }


    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T) {
        mutableLiveData.value = value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't. The [requirements](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html#property-delegate-requirements) include:

> `getValue()` must return the same type as the property (or its subtype).

> `value` [argument of `setValue`] must be of the same type as the property (or its supertype).

and there's no type `P` you could use for property such that both: `Result<T>` is `P` or a subtype of `P`; and `T` is `P` or a supertype of `P`.

But you can just add a method taking `T` instead of making it a setter:

```
// inside SafeMutableLiveData
fun set(value: T) {
    mutableLiveData.value = Result.Success(value)
}
```